Help with Performance counters for OOS
I have OOS 2019 Farm running without SP.
I looked through performance counters called "office online - ...", but there are too much of them.
Currently I need to know count of active open editor browsers per farm and maximum simultaneous editors per document - like this:
If user A opens for editing Doc1.xlsx, Doc2.pptx and Doc3.docx, and user B opens Doc2.pptx, Doc3.docx, Doc4.xlsx, I want counters:
Total opened editors: 6 (each A and B opened 3 browser tabs)
Total edited files: 4 (overlapping Doc2 and Doc3)
Total opened Excel editors: 2 (A:Doc1 and B:Doc4)
Total opened PP editors: 2 (A:Doc2 and B:Doc2)
Total opened Word editors: 2 (A:Doc3 and B:Doc3)
Maximum simultaneous editors in Excel editors: 1 (A:Doc1 and B:Doc4 not overlapping)
Maximum simultaneous editors in PP editors: 2 (A:Doc2 and B:Doc2 overlapping)
Maximum simultaneous editors in Word editors: 2 (A:Doc3 and B:Doc3 overlapping)

